# Generic tuple mapped to array tuple function arguments

Tags: typescript

I'd like to essentially create a function that accepts an tuple of tuples. In this context, it would be a tuple of get / set functions. So in the following format

```
type T = [
  [get: (index: number) => A, set: (index: number) => (value: A) => void],
  [get: (index: number) => B, set: (index: number) => (value: B) => void],
  [get: (index: number) => C, set: (index: number) => (value: C) => void],
  ...
];
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` are distinct types I would like inferred according to the arg provided.

As of now, I've tried to have a generic that extends `any[]` hoping that each member of this tuple would represent one of the distinct types shown above.

```
type DataItem = {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly value: string;
};

const data: DataItem[] = [];

type Arg<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: readonly [
    get: (index: number) => T[I],
    set: (index: number) => (value: T[I]) => void,
  ];
};

const createGetSet = <T extends any[]>(arg: Arg<T>) => {};

createGetSet([
  [
    (i) => data[i],
    (i) => (value) => {
      data[i] = value;
    },
  ],
]);
```

This works for the getter, but the type of the argument `value` is resolved as `any` rather than somehow being tied to the getter type as passed when calling the function.

I thought maybe typing the function tuple itself as the generic might help but I'm not sure how that would work as I did not find a way to have the return and arg type as connected so just put them as unknown which does not really work.

```
const createGetSet = <
  T extends [
    get: (index: number) => unknown,
    set: (index: number) => (value: unknown) => void,
  ][],
>(
  arg: T,
) => {};

createGetSet([
  [
    (i) => data[i],
    (i) => (value) => {
      data[i] = value;
    },
  ],
]);
```

Here is a link to a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=68&ssc=6&pln=52&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBJYEC2UC8UDeBYAKCigCcI4ATAewDsAbEKASwoC4oaBXNAIwhIDchYmUq0GUAG5w6nCOwDOwEkxoBzIQQC%20mwgGNaSqBQRx28RCnQBtALpYod3QXxEoAendQAYkxJGEVDQwYHY1CBp%20Jj0oCAAPVBoKBSg4GhA7ABooZRBVNRyqKAALOElocj1iqDR0PhIoKgAzHM4wOmhgIr4c4oq4yD1UChzwCGFRyCgAQRI1AB4AFViEiOTU9LsAPgdXYmJrJGYaKABrCBBmqEXbdlFqekZrCf2ocNCoAApVCnj2Ll4-AAlFgdotDrZMi99goIB9vkk-hxuPUQZgdp9pLJ5NcIWidpIqCwoW5iLZNMQdIQJgYaEY9KJUABxOEAZThDiWK0S6zSGVsW0%20cDm7FmC0WW3xuCpBBpjIgLOA7OAn2epMc0OI3ylJkQ1iYkM1XyYUsxMjkUr2r32urg%20vs2Cxcgp1q0JNehrctiBmi01JcE08UHZtJGgXQIXYrLgtVSKSafiMPE4wCgsIg%20WYLUoFEzcDTEFDbwiURiaDg5xS%20dzTSa-AienGblAUzFXPiPKrmwFu2hh2OZwuVxud3IDwkautxfhPyRANRoNxSE9U9hM8RcX%20KOBi7N2PY4OXUsJxOh5ImMpphlTDPIzLZHOw7dWSS7-OyrO5axSbYlguFahRpal5uLeCAKg%20KqTvs0GvNqi62va7rWvB6JfE6ECWkaxCIQaDgYS6rxumeyHer6-pWkGizFH4YbAEEkbXCQeTqIUNQVp0fTFpEKgxMAXFNJwNBDEwtCtO00BMMAsJ0C0yapvxEQcFQqYKJwZAlFQADuUBHAYnB0CMPA-L00BkMA6knC2nRFAB3ARApYxXnSN7yoqyqctCywdt%20GrqsQ7zsAivybsigIkFKQmnDQ2k0MhrxrkFs6hfOO5oXucjsFFMVaTQx5EhQ8VQLYWQTIK0IAQeyHAc4xBgfeSpwqqfZGqhOy4SuKEmruGFYf5NqmPa%20HmhAhH7MR6qdWRhB%20gQQA) with some of the attempts. I appreciate any feedback or guidance, thanks.

Comment: it's clear to me what data you expect to pass type-check. but whicharguments should throw type error?

Comment: In my opinion it does not matter which argument should throw the error. I think it will naturally follow that the second one will throw the error as inference should occur on the first.